# Use WTForms with webapp and Django templates on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, wtforms

I'm trying to use WTForms with webapp without much luck.

I would like to be able to use the `form_field` templatetag, as shown in the documentation:

`{% form_field form.username class="big_text" onclick="do_something()" %}`

I've got WTForms installed fine in my application, but its Django template tags isn't working for me. Does anyone have instructions on how to get this installed?

If I can't get this working, I will probably give up and switch to Jinja2 templates. The reason we have kept with Django so far is to limit the number of dependencies as much as possible.

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've install Django 1.1 locally and enabled it [per the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django).

I tried adding `INSTALLED_APPS = ['wtforms.ext.django']` to my `settings.py` - no effect.

I tried registering the wtforms templatetag manually:.

```
register = webapp.template.create_template_register()

from wtforms.ext.django.templatetags import wtforms

register.tag('form_field', wtforms.do_form_field)
```

This gave me an error: `InvalidTemplateLibrary: Could not load template library from template_helpers, No module named django.templatetags`

So I tried copying and pasting the template tags into my own code, and I got the error `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ' form.foobar' from 'form_field form.foobar`.

However, I don't think the templatetag registration worked, because the error was the same without that code.

---

**Update:** I'm leaving this question up in case someone on the internet can some day answer it, but I switched to Jinja2 and now everything works perfectly. Webapp with Django templates is dead to me. ;-)

Comment: i went in with same sort of errors and have documented things over, for some one who comes seeking soln. following article might be of help: http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/06/Modelforms-for-appengine-models-with-WTForms-and-debugging-with-pdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend jinja2 templates over django: http://jinja.pocoo.org/ It's based on the django templates but more powerful and easy to use. I don't think it's a good idea to use Django templates without the django stack. Also, if you want a more structured framework, a VERY nice minimalist framework is Flask: http://www.pocoo.org/projects/flask/#flask. I can't praise those two libraries enough. I worked a long time in Django and found this combo to be very refreshing and succinct.

P.S. this should be a very simple process to port over. It took me 10 minutes to port over a webapp site when I just found out about Flask.

Comment: A good writeup of how to migrate from webapp to flask: http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-flask-on-google-app-engine/